# Propositional Logic (A→C) ∧ (C→¬B) ∧ B→¬A

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Hey guys I'm struggling to figure out how to solve the question:
 (A→C) ∧ (C→¬B) ∧ B→¬A using propositional logic.

I've tried rewriting (C→¬B) to other forms, but I don't think I can because of the negation of B.

Any suggestions / tips?

Comment: What is the question? What you have is just a propositional sentence. What are you trying to do?

Comment: do you want to prove that it is a tautology or what?

Comment: [This tool](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#(A%E2%86%92C)%20%E2%88%A7%20(C%E2%86%92%C2%ACB)%20%E2%88%A7%20B%E2%86%92%C2%ACA%20) might be of use to you.

Answer (score 0):

(A→C) ∧ (C→¬B) ∧ B → ¬A

B and the contrapositive of C→¬B gives not-C

not-C and the contrapositive of A→C gives not-A